# Strange behavior of React hooks: delayed data update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Strange behavior: I expect that the first and the second console.log display a different result, but they display the same result and the value is changed only on the next click. How should I edit my code so that the value will be different?

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(false);
  const test = () => {
    console.log(count); //false
    setCount(!count);
    console.log(count); //false
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={test}>Hello StackOverflow</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can see a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wz9y5lqyzk

Comment: Note: Please put your runnable example **here, on site** rather than offsite by using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The state update is asynchronous so if you are using Hooks you can use `useEffect` to be notified after an update.

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wxy342m6l

If you are using setState of a React component, you can use the callback

`this.setState((state) => ({count: !state.count}), () => console.log('Updated', this.state.count));`

Remember to use the callback to update state if you need a state value.

Comment: I had an edit form in React Native that did not contain information at first. Then I called the form information like your code. My problem is solved

Answer (score 9):

[State updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). The `setCount` function you get from [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) can't magically reach out and change the value of your `count` constant. For one thing, it's a constant. For another, `setCount` doesn't have access to it. Instead, when you call `setCount`, your component function will get called again, and `useState` will return the updated count.

Live Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  const test = () =>{
    setCount(!count); // Schedules asynchronous call to Example, re-rendering the component
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={test}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>Count: {String(count)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to perform some side-effect when `count` changes, use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`count changed to ${count}`);
}, [count]);
```

Notice that we tell `useEffect` to only call our callback when `count` changes, so that if we have other state, our callback doesn't run unnecessarily.

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  const test = () =>{
    setCount(!count); // Schedules asynchronous call to Example, re-rendering the component
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`count changed to ${count}`);
  }, [count]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={test}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>Count: {String(count)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

The `setState` hook doesn't update the value in the component directly. It updates it's internal state, causes a rerender of the component, and then returns the new state value, which you assign to `count`.

When you `console.log(count)` inside `test`, you display the current value of `count`, which is the old value (before the update). If you'll move the `console.log()` to the render, you'll see the new value:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Component = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);

  const test = () => {
    console.log('before: ', count);
    setCount(!count)
  }
  
  console.log('after: ', count);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={test}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Component />,
   demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```