# Why do I have two different values on this boolean in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, state

In the React Native App, after I click the toggle button, the function *_toggleServerSwitch* gets triggered. Then I change the state *serverSwitchValue* to the same value as *x*.

**Expected**: *serverSwitchValue* and *x* should have the same value when *console.log()*.

**Actual**: When console.log(), the two variables have different values.

It seems that the program works, but at the time when *console.log()* gets triggered, the values are not the same. Why?

```
const [serverSwitchValue, setServerSwitchValue] = useState(false);

  const _toggleServerSwitch = x => {
    setServerSwitchValue(x);
    console.log('x is: ' + x);
    console.log('serverSwitchValue is: ' + serverSwitchValue);
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange behavior of React hooks: delayed data update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983047/strange-behavior-of-react-hooks-delayed-data-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setServerSwitchValue() is an async function , so it doesnt imply that you will get the values updated instantly. YOu can use `useEffect` as below :

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(serverSwitchValue);
}, [serverSwitchValue]); // Only re-run the effect if open changes
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did not know it is asynchronous, now it makes sense. Thank you!